# commands need to be execute to run cron job

Tags: cron

we don't have cpanel access, we are using amazon web service and we are using putty ssh.

we want to check cron job is working or not, so i installed this extension : https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

its displaying cron job is not working.

so i want to use this : `http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_jo`b

they mentioned like this for unix based systems : http://pastebin.com/WXeGVPxJ

i am new to these ssh commands.

Can anyone please inform me what commands ,i have to run in above link to install cron job successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to execute many commands, the most important thing is that you edit your crontab file. I don't know how this works on Amazon's servers, usually you can do it via `crontab -e` though (e for edit).

In that file you need to add a new rule which calls the `cron.php` every so often. The format of this is (borrowed from your link):

> `* * * * *  /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh`

Format of this: The first 5 stars stand for minutes, hours, days, weeks and months. Then the shell which you want to run your script (just use /bin/sh) and finally the path to your `cron.sh` which you need to look up yourself (in your Magento root usually).

We're doing this every minute, because `cron.php` will take care which scripts to run when and just needs a heartbeat.

If you successfully add this line as I described above and Amazon didn't disable cron jobs or something, this should work.

Comment: we are using ubuntu server

and run following commands, 

crontab -u user -e  and  

*/1 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/html/totaltoys/cron.sh

is this enough?

using that extension, still we are getting error : No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly.

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 could you check what's in your crontab? (just do crontab -e and check what's there)

Comment: please check this : http://prntscr.com/74p745

Comment: ok this seems ok, please try running the script directly and see if there are any errors. do `sh /path/to/cron.sh` in a terminal and resolve or report back any errors

Comment: you're very welcome :)